# Need advise about working with remote git repo

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I have git situation like below and im new to git too :

- On remote we have Development branch and i have cloned it
- I have checkout Development and create new Branch called A01
- I have done Push the branch A01 and create Pull Request on A01
- A01 reviewed and merge to remote Development repo
- I do made some changes in Projects file but for local environment only (not pushed)

What should i do if i have to create new branch (ex:A02) to implement new feature
In my thinking there are 2 options :

- Merge local Development br with A01 br
- Git pull for Development branch(remote) (but when i do this, some msg showing : The pull would overwrite your local changes to the following 2 files ... )

Please advise, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do made some changes in Projects file but for local environment only
> (not pushed)

What you need to do depends on what you want to do with your local changes.

#### You don't want your local changes to be part of any remote branch.

- Do `git stash`. This will clear your working tree and index tree in your repo
- Do `git pull`. It should complete successfully.
- At later point, when you want these changes back you can do `git stash apply`. Remember, you might get merge conflict while applying it back. You need to resolve them.

#### You want your local changes to be part of develop branch (remote as well) immediately

- Stage and commit your local changes.
- Then execute `git pull`. You might get merge conflict, you need to resolve them.

#### You want your local changes to be part of remote branch but not for now.

**One option is to create a new branch to track your local changes.**

- Run, `git checkout -b <new branch name>`
- `git checkout develop`
- `git pull`
- Later when you want to work on your local changes, you can do `git checkout <new branch name>`

**Another option,**

- you can commit your changes to local develop branch.
- you can create A02 out of remote branch directly as `git checkout -b A02 origin/develop` (Assuming your remote repo name uses the default name, origin.)